# OTRS Installation on AWS Linux AMI results in 500 Internal Server Error page

Tags: apache-2.4, perl, otrs

I am creating a new instance of OTRS on Amazon Linux AMI 2017.03.0 (HVM) and cannot get the installer.pl to run. My installation steps are as follows (and I've done this about four times so far):

- Set the HOSTNAME
- Add the private IP address to the hosts file with the FQDN of the server (172.10.10.10 otrs.example.com)
- `sudo yum -y update`
- `sudo yum -y install bash-completion --enablerepo=epel`
- `wget http://ftp.otrs.org/pub/otrs/RPMS/rhel/ ... noarch.rpm`
- `sudo yum -y install --nogpgcheck otrs-5.0.18-01.noarch.rpm`
- `sudo yum install -y mod24_perl "perl(JSON::XS)" "perl(GD::Text)" "perl(Encode::HanExtra)" "perl(GD::Graph)" "perl(Mail::IMAPClient)" "perl(PDF::API2)" "perl(Text::CSV_XS)" "perl(YAML::XS)" "perl(DBD::mysql)"`
- `sudo /sbin/chkconfig httpd on`
- `sudo reboot`

SELinux is disabled. Following a reboot, I can get to the Amazon Linux AMI Test Page but not otrs.example.com/otrs/installer.pl (results in a 500 Internal Server Error).

My httpd_error logs shows:

```
[Thu Apr 20 22:21:31.894716 2017] [core:notice] [pid 2721] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin//opt/'
[Thu Apr 20 22:21:41.067143 2017] [:error] [pid 2725] Cannot find current script '/opt/' at /usr/share/perl5/FindBin.pm line 166.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/FindBin.pm line 166.\nCompilation failed in require at /opt/otrs/bin/cgi-bin/installer.pl line 25.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/otrs/bin/cgi-bin/installer.pl line 25.\n
[Thu Apr 20 22:21:48.280174 2017] [:error] [pid 2726] Cannot find current script '/opt/' at /usr/share/perl5/FindBin.pm line 166.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/FindBin.pm line 166.\nCompilation failed in require at /opt/otrs/bin/cgi-bin/installer.pl line 25.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/otrs/bin/cgi-bin/installer.pl line 25.\n
[Thu Apr 20 22:58:25.283392 2017] [autoindex:error] [pid 2724] [client 64.62.178.49:52639] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

Comment: @Frederik Nielsen Thank you for cleaning up my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't figure out what was wrong exactly but it concerned specifying `mod24_perl`. This install works on Amazon Linux:

- `sudo yum -y install --nogpgcheck otrs-5.0.18-01.noarch.rpm`
- `sudo yum install -y "perl(Crypt::Eksblowfish::Bcrypt)" "perl(JSON::XS)" "perl(GD::Text)" "perl(Encode::HanExtra)" "perl(GD::Graph)" "perl(Mail::IMAPClient)" "perl(PDF::API2)" "perl(Text::CSV_XS)" "perl(YAML::XS)" "perl(DBD::mysql)"`

I thought I had attempted an install like this in the beginning but must have misconfigured something then.